# How to generate a JSON string compatible with Objective-C syntax

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I need some kind of json string generator for objective-c. Actually I thought there must be something like that but I could not find anything.To be specific, for example I have a json string like:

```
{"name":"abc","email":"def@ghi.com","password":"1"}
```

when I want to store it in objective c, I have to write it like:

```
@"{\"name\":""\"abc\""",\"email\":""\"def@ghi.com\""",\"password\":""\"1\"""}"
```

so it is confusing and hard to implement. Are there any generators or an easy way to implement it. Thanks

Comment: You have a JSON string like that *where*?  In a file??  What do you mean by "store it in objective c"?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your json string to dictionary...

```
NSData* data = [yourJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:data
                                      options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error];
 NSLog(@"jsonDict:%@",jsonDict);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native ios SDK API's for generating JSON data from NSDictionary / NSArray.

e.g.,

```
NSData *jsondata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:(dictobject) options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsondata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

may this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use it
Also Import"JSON.H"

```
 NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:website] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

be careful...in your original question, when referring to how to store it in objective-c, i think you made a mistake

you wrote : 
    @"{\"name\":""\"abc\"""

when it shoud be
    @"{\"name\":\"abc\",....etc...

i think you doubled the quotes...be wary, cause in the beginning there already is one opening double-quote @", all the other needed quotes must be escaped like so \", and then also have an ending quote as well.

hope it helps